# what does each instruction do in the unmarshall code?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

i'm trying to learn how to unmarshall an xml file and i found the following code on internet and wanted to understand each instruction, 
any help ?

ps : here's the link to the website where i found the code :https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-unmarshal-example/

```
File file = new File("museums.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Museums.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Museums museums = (Museums) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(museums);
```

Comment: This question is maybe a bit on the broad side. Surely you know what `File file = ...` and `System.out.println()` means. Are you really asking why we need a separate `JAXBContext` and `Unmarshaller`?

Comment: ofc. what i don't get is the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JAXBContext` is the entry point of all JAXB operations, in practice there are three you might want to use:

1. Marshal
2. Unmarshal
3. Generate schema

When you create it, you give it one or more classes on which you plan to perform the operations above. It will then look up those classes, read their JAXB annotations and configure itself accordingly.

*You need to create it with `JAXBContext.newInstance()` instead of directly instantiating it because JAXB is an API that has multiple pluggable implementations.*

Then you get the `Unmarshaller` belonging to the context, which is the  object responsible for converting an XML document into a Java object (and also for validating said document).

Lastly, you tell the unmarshaller to process your specific file, resulting in the Java object you wanted.

Of course unmarshallers can do lots of other things (work from sources  other than a file for example), but for that you need to check the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html).

P.s.: From Java 8 onwards you can also use the convenience class [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html). Although it comes with certain caveats, it can save a lot of hassle.

Comment: thanks a lot, i wanted to know this cuz i tried this code with my xml file ( did all the necessary changes  ) but i got the refrence of the root element as an output